# Shape not getting applied to Button Selector in Android

Tags: android

Shape Radius defined in xml is not getting applied to Button Focus & Pressed state.

I have 
**instagram_button_style.xml** as below:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_button_shape" android:state_focused="true" android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_button_shape" android:state_pressed="true" android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorButton" />

</selector>
```

and My **instagram_button_shape.xml** as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorButton" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_gradient" >
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Where 
**instagram_gradient** is a jpg image

[image]

Using it in button like :

`android:background="@drawable/instagram_button_style"`

**My Initial Button State:**

[image]

**My Pressed Button State**

[image]

**Expectation:** I was expecting pressed state to have oval button, but Radius is not getting applied.

**FINAL Update:**

At last, after numerous research I ended up changing my .JPG gradient file to android_gradient shape file.

Comment: Your `@drawable/instagram_gradient` item layer is above the solid color layer that has rounded corners, but doesn't have corners set for itself.

Comment: How to set corners for drawble in this scenario?

Comment: @Cruceo: I updated my shape.xml in question, Now I can see initial shaped in oval shape, but still not seeing pressed state as Oval shape

Comment: Simply wrap your button inside CardView and apply cardCornerRadius of 30dp

Comment: @RahulKhurana : isn't there a simpler way, which involves conventional way

Comment: @kushal.8 None of them i know. according to your requirements this is the simplest way i can come out

Comment: its really strange that you are getting the initial button state with corner, the above code must always show a rectangle for all state not only when its pressed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set **`android:radius="30dp"`** in your `@drawable/instagram_gradient`

Try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tvKioskMode"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/instagram_button_style"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="OPEN IN"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> drawable/instagram_button_style

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_button_shape" android:state_selected="true" android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_button_shape" android:state_pressed="true" android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_button" />
</selector>
```

> @drawable/instagram_button_shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_gradient" >
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

> @drawable/normal_button

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

> @drawable/instagram_gradient

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#00E5FF"
        android:endColor="#FF1744"
        android:startColor="#3D5AFE"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners
        android:radius="30dp"/>

</shape>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

> @drawable/instagram_button_style

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_button_shape" android:state_selected="true" android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_button_shape" android:state_pressed="true" android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_button" />
</selector>
```

> @drawable/instagram_button_shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_gradient"/>

</layer-list>
```

> @drawable/my_gradient

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>


    <!--add here your instagram image-->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/insta_gradient_image"
        android:bottom="30dp"
        android:left="30dp"
        android:right="30dp"
        android:top="30dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

> @drawable/normal_button

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

Comment: My `instagram_gradient` is a .JPG file not an android gradient

Comment: I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: Only the color is getting changed on click

Comment: @kushal.8 can u add that insta-gragient image in you question

Comment: Updated in my  question

Answer (score 2):

try this to change `instagram_button_shape.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorButton" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="30dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_gradient"
        android:left="30dp"
        android:right="30dp"
        android:top="30dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorButton" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: I'll try and let you know, Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The [`<layer-list>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) has items, and you define this item incorrectly:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_gradient">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Indeed, [`android:drawable` defines the Drawable used to render the layer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#attr_android:drawable). The nested shape is just ignored.

You have three options to reach your goal:

- use a shape with a gradient, and remove the `android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_gradient"`
- use a PNG with transparency and rounded corners for the the `@drawable/instagram_gradient`
- and of course implement a custom `Drawable`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is wrap your button with [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView). It has property called [CornerRadius](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView#cardview_cardcornerradius). That way you can round your button into custom corner shape.

Answer (score -1):

Try this Updated,

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_button_shape" 
    android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/instagram_button_shape"  />
<item android:drawable="@color/colorButton" />

 </selector>
```

now, when you click this botton set

```
buttonId.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: Thanks "Genius" ;)

Comment: Genius, It's Not Working!

Comment: <item android:drawable="@color/colorButton" />   remove this. above code is working!